# install a kernel module into BeagleBoard (BB)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel-modules

I want to install a kernel module (For example "Hello world") on the BeagleBoard(BB). (The installed OS on the BB is an Ubuntu Linux).

If anybody already worked on this could you suggest me a step by step instruction? Any suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with doing it the normal way?

Comment: i am new to this environment but i didn't clarify with the steps which is available onto, net if anybody have a getting started kind of link for beginner on this topic like kernel module on Beagleboard please share with me...

Comment: Which steps did you try to perform in order to solve this? Where did you encounter any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

`insmod modulename.so`